# c# Remove oldest items from hash set

Tags: c#

I have a simple mechanism that adds items to hash set, but when it reaches certain number of items i want it to remove oldest items, so I tried with RemoveWhere

```
    private void RestrictResponseCache()
    {            
        if (ResponseCahce.Count > this.ResponseCahceLimit * 2)
        {
            ResponseCahce.RemoveWhere(response => ResponseCahce.Count < this.ResponseCahceLimit * 2);
        }
    }
```

But it seems not to remove oldest items, well it does nothing. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: How many items you want to remove from `ResponseCahce`

Comment: For example i have 20 items limit so in my understanding it will check on every add item if that item number has been crossed, is so remove all items that are beneath 20 counting from last item.

Comment: This won't work. First `RemoveWhere` needs a predicate to match the item to remove. Secondly, you'd end up just removing a random selection of items, as HashSet does not maintain the order you add items.

Comment: Do you have any property to handle Order like, `CreatedDateTime`, `Number/ID`

Comment: It seems that you might be looking for something called LRU cache

Comment: You're not actually accessing any property from `response` to see if it should be removed. The given check there will return the same value for every item it's run over.